# Environment variable not changing as I hope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I set the value "Test" to ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT using PowerShell, but when I start my app, it gets the value from launchSettings.json.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Test", "Machine")
```

If I remove the value from launchSettings.json, the value changes to "Production", not to "Test".

What am I doing wrong?

I will deploy it to two different apps on AWS Beanstalk and I will send a script file to change the environment variable.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

My launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60511/",
      "sslPort": 44392
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "myapp",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MonitoraApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "myapp",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60512"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you used [AddEnvironmentVariables(IConfigurationBuilder, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.environmentvariablesextensions.addenvironmentvariables?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_EnvironmentVariablesExtensions_AddEnvironmentVariables_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationBuilder_System_String_). You could try showing us some code.

Comment: Are you adding it to the environment of whatever user is running the ASP service?

Comment: Are you running you're app within the same powershell script? Powershell can only set env vars for the current session, they are reverted when the script ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an expected behavious as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments#development):

> The environment for local machine development can be set in the `Properties\launchSettings.json` file of the project. Environment values set in launchSettings.json override values set in the system environment.

So the answer to your question ("*What am I doing wrong?*") is as follows:
you're not supposed to use `launchsettings.json` in production (so just remove it and ignore from source control or modify deployment script so that it doesn't copy this file). 
`launchsettings.json` is a tool to facilitate easy tests on the development machine.

Comment: You understood my doubts perfectly. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I could get the value "Test" by executing your PowerShell command and the following code:

```
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  Why in the world should I have to tell `GetEnvironmentVariable` to use `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine`?  I have been banging my head against this wall for 1.5 days until I found your answer.  Wish I could upvote more.